# Unable to upload jar file to nexus repository where as .pom file gets uploaded

Tags: maven, deployment, jar, nexus, artifact

I have a maven project and i am trying to deploy generated jar file to nexus repository.

added below code to settings.xml and placed in .m2 folder

```
<server>
<id>testrepo</id>
<username>admin</username>
<password>#########</password>
</server>

 <mirror>
      <id>testrepo</id>
      <mirrorOf>testrepo</mirrorOf>
      <name>testrepo</name>
      <url>http://artifacts.com/repository/testrepo</url>
    </mirror>
```

Added pom file below

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>testse</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>001</version>
    <name>cloud</name>
    <description>framework</description>
    <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>testrepo</id>
      <name>testrepo</name>
      <url>http://artifacts.com/repository/testrepo</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
  </distributionManagement>
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>testrepo</id>
            <url>https://artifacts.com/repository/testrepo</url>
        </repository> 

        
  </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-cli/commons-cli -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-exec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-exec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-net/commons-net -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/fontbox -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.collections/google-collections -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna-platform -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jar/junit.jar -->





        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okio/okio -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okio</groupId>
            <artifactId>okio</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openpnp/opencv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0-3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-examples -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-examples</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-excelant -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-edge-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-edge-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-firefox-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-ie-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server-standalone -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.standalone</groupId>
  <artifactId>lenium</artifactId>
  <version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
  <groupId>oracle.ctadf</groupId>
  <artifactId>webdriver</artifactId>
  <version>11</version>
</dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sikulix/sikulixapi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
            <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xmlpull/xmlpull -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlpull</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlpull</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xpp3/xpp3_min -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>xpp3_min</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4c</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.thoughtworks.xstream/xstream -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <!-- <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>  -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                    
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**.pom file is getting uploaded to nexus repository but .jar file is getting failed with Error code 401, Unauthorized**

Please help, Thanks!

Comment: Please show the full pom file...

Comment: @khmarbaise  updated question with pom file code ..please have a look

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: you have pdfbox and fontbox of different (very old) versions. Try 1.8.16 or 2.0.26. Also check your other versions with the maven versions plugin.